# Derived class nested inside base class - C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to transform the following JAVA code to C++ code. But unable to figure out how.

```java
abstract class Base {
   static class Derived extends Base {
      // attributes

      Derived(/*params list*/) {
        // code
      }


}
```

When I try to do something like below, the compiler says `Base` is not complete until the closing brace. I understand that things don't work the same way as JAVA, but I am unable to figure out how to reproduce this code in C++.

```cpp
class Base {
        class Derived: public Base{
        // attributes
        Derived(/* param list*/);
    };
 };
```

Is it possible to do this in C++? Open to non-object-oriented approaches too.

Comment: As I have no Java experience: Why the derived class should be a subclass of Base?

Comment: I am trying to build an abstract syntax tree for a language grammar. So, need to have the class to be deduced multiple different ways and to be recursive. I am following [this online book.](https://craftinginterpreters.com/representing-code.html)

Comment: I have no technical basis for this, but I suspect that this convoluted usage is an artifact of writing the original code in Java and not an essential part of the solution being discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done. Just add a forward declaration to the body of `Base` and move the definition below the definition of `Base`:

```
class Base
{
    class Derived;
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
protected:
    Base() = default; // only allow initialization for subclasses to make this "abstract" without introducing a pure virtual function
};

class Base::Derived : public Base
{
    // attributes

    Derived(/*params list*/) {
        // code
    }
};
```